# Lightning Components Basics : Attributes and Expressions Challenge

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforcedx

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="item" type="Camping_Item__c" required="true"/>
    <p>Name:{!v.item.Name}</p>
    <p>Price:
    <lightning:formattedNumber value="{!v.item.Price__c}" style="currency"/>
    </p>
    <p>Quantity:
        <lightning:formattedNumber value="{!v.item.Quantity__c}" style="number"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <lightning:input type="toggle"
                         label="Packed?"
                         name="Packed"
                         checked="{!v.item.Packed__c}"/>                         
    </p>
</aura:component>
```

While saving this code i am getting this error

[image]

And After that while checking challenge it's showing :
The campingListItem Lightning Component's attribute tag doesn't exist or its attributes are not set correctly.

Comment: Did you create the Camping_Item__c object?

Comment: Yes, I created .

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but it would be a good idea to check that you have the case of `Camping_Item__c` correct. Apex is not case sensitive, but Javascript is. Also check your profile to make sure you have access to this object.

Answer (score 0):

try to give a default=' ' because you have required is true for item attribute.

Comment: I tried default=' ' as you said . Still I got same problem .

Comment: Beside what @Caspar Harmer said, copy the API name of your object just to be sure.

Comment: Thank you guys I solved my question.